# Adding regions in Notepad for PHP

Tags: php, notepad++

I have seen how to use a user defined language, but I would like to know if it is possible to add a #region for code folding into Notepad's ++ PHP. I tried using #region x and #end region - it works, but only if I don't close and reopen the PHP code in between, which makes it a bit useless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding might help...

Comment: @Raad Thank you! I had read that already tough, and my problem is adding that code into the PHP interpreter... there are some suggestions in the comments but I couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a built-in language for NPP, and judging from previous attempts to do this sort of thing, I think the only course is to create a new language definition file by opening up the `langs.model.xml` and `stylers.model.xml` files, and combining the PHP sections into a new php user defined language file. Use an existing one from the SourceForge "User_Defined_Language_Files" page (listed below) as a template.

Unfortunately it isn't a 1-1 correspondence between the entries in the built-in files and what is needed in a UDL file, so you will have a certain amount of translating to do; but if you succeed, you will be able to define your own keywords for folding.

Some references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575865/extending-language-definitions-for-code-highlighting-in-notepad
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages

Good luck!